# Which tree decomposition of a graph is preferrable?

Tags: graphs, trees

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition) page, there are two examples of tree decomposition of a graph $G$.

[image: Tree decomposition]

Could there be another decomposition such as:
$\{A,B\}, \{C,E,F\}, \{D,F,G\}$

or did I get the rules of decomposition wrong? Must two adjacent vertices of the tree share two vertices of the graph?

And considering these decompositions, which one is better than the others? Or is there no "better" decomposition as long as it is a correct decomposition?

Answer (score 4):

A tree decomposition of smaller width is generally preferable over one of larger width.

The "decomposition" you've listed is not a tree decomposition since (a) you haven't given the tree structure and (b) it violates the requirement that for each edge $(u,v)$ there is a bag containing both $u$ and $v$. For instance, there's no bag containing both $B$ and $C$.

In general, a tree decomposition must satisfy these 3 requirements:

- Every vertex must be contained in some bag
- For every edge $(u,v)$ there must be a bag containing $u$ and $v$
- The subgraph of the tree induced by bags containing a specific vertex is connected